# How to create a catch for data type

Tags: c++, string, int, try-catch

I have been making some simple programs such as number guessing games, betting games, etc. One thing I am trying to do in these programs is to create a catch for inputting the wrong data type. So if I had the variable `int num;` and the user inputted a string, is there a way to recognize if the data entered does not match the data type of the declared variable and ask to re-input it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The C++ IOstream library does that for you. by default, [`std::istream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream) objects will fail if [formatted extraction](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt) operations fail.

So when you have something like this.

```
int num;

if(!(std::cin >> num)){
    //operation failed
}
```

If the user enters characters other than numbers. `std::cin` will fail. Hence all you need to do is to check the status of the `stream` object to know if a formatted input succeeded

> is there a way to recognize if the data entered does not match the
>   data type of the declared variable and ask to re-input it?

You could do something like this:

```
#include <limits> //for std::numeric_limits
#include <ios>    //for std::streamsize
......

int num;
while(!(std::cin >> num)){
    std::cerr << "Please enter a valid number!\n";
    std::cin.clear();
    std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
}
```

EDIT:

As *user4581301* pointed out in the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40273698/how-to-create-a-catch-for-data-type/40273741#comment67807216_40273741), there are a few corner cases to watch out for.

A slight improvement hack for `ints/floats` hullabalo may be:

```
while(!(std::cin >> num) || std::cin.get() == static_cast<int>('.') ){
    std::cerr << "Please enter a valid number!\n";
    std::cin.clear();
    std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
}
```

Note, that this hack only applies to `ints`

Comment: The usual warning that input of 3.14 will result in a valid `int`, 3, and a .4 waiting in the stream to wreak havoc on the next read.

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me. The only thing that didn't work was that when I put that in a while loop or if statement, it didn't just execute it once but for the entirety of the code where I have string inputs. Is there some way to end that check?

Comment: You could use a `for` loop to end the check.. By simply replacing `while(!(std::cin >> num))` with `for(int i = 0; i < 5 && !(std::cin >> num)); i++)`. That will do at most 5 retries.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can store the input of the user on a string; then use `stoi` or a similar function to convert it back to int (or other type). That function can thow an exception if the conversion is invalid.

I did something similar here: https://gist.github.com/illescasDaniel/40ad9811af35855132d7588d08bf672a

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/14109543)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre This **is an answer.** Without the link, the body remains as "Well, you can store the input of the user on a string; then use stoi or a similar function to convert it back to int (or other type). That function can thow an exception if the conversion is invalid." which is an answer. Also [read this post.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287563/youre-doing-it-wrong-a-plea-for-sanity-in-the-low-quality-posts-queue)

Comment: I never failed a review audit and I always review posts carefully. However, this answer is prone to be downvoted and it is low quality. Ok, maybe the reason is incorrect but it is still a bad answer.